# Generating fresh wallets for a telegram bot

Tags: wallet

I was looking to make my very own telegram bot and wanted it to generate Wallets which the bot would manage, but I cannot find any documentation about wallet generation from a telegram request.
If anyone could provide some clues about how to achieve that, it would be great help.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a new wallet in typescript using [`Keypair.generate()`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Keypair.html) from web3.js and using [`Keypair::new()`](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/signer/keypair/struct.Keypair.html) in Rust from the solana-sdk crate. I'll leave it to you to decide in which language you want to write your bot in, but this is how you'd generate a new wallet in the two most prominent ones in the solana ecosystem.